# How can I change the number of tables?

Tags: tables

How can I change the number of tables? means not auto numbering.
[image]

because the typesetting number is wrong. so I want to change the number of this table. for example the table numbering 1\2\3\4, I want change to 1\3\2\4, just change one or two tables number.

my code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf} 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol, nonfloat}  %% for two columns. NEVER REMOVE!!
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Rules of selecting $e_{q}$.}\label{tab:1}
\centering%
{\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}
{|m{42pt}<{\centering}|m{46pt}<{\centering}|m{46pt}<{\centering}|m{46pt}<{\centering}|}
\hline
$L_{i}$& $E_{M_{0}}$ < - $E_{M}^{T}$ & $|E_{M_{0}}|\leq E_{M}^{T}$ & $|E_{M_{0}}| > E_{M}^{T}$ \\ \hline
$L_{3} \& L_{4} $& $e_{5}$ & $e_{3}$ & $-$ \\ \hline
$L_{1}$& $e_{3}$ & $e_{1}$ & $e_{2}$ \\ \hline
$L_{2}$& $e_{1}$ & $e_{1}$ & $e_{2}$ \\ \hline
$L_{5}$& $-$ & $e_{2}$ & $e_{4}$ \\ \hline
$L_{6}$& $-$ & $e_{4}$ & $e_{4}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Rules of selecting $e_{q}$.}\label{tab:3}
\centering%
{\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}
{|m{42pt}<{\centering}|m{46pt}<{\centering}|m{46pt}<{\centering}|m{46pt}<{\centering}|}
\hline
$L_{i}$& $E_{M_{0}}$ < - $E_{M}^{T}$ & $|E_{M_{0}}|\leq E_{M}^{T}$ & $|E_{M_{0}}| > E_{M}^{T}$ \\ \hline
$L_{3} \& L_{4} $& $e_{5}$ & $e_{3}$ & $-$ \\ \hline
$L_{5}$& $-$ & $e_{2}$ & $e_{4}$ \\ \hline
$L_{6}$& $-$ & $e_{4}$ & $e_{4}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Rules of selecting $e_{q}$.}\label{tab:2}
\centering%
{\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}
{|m{42pt}<{\centering}|m{46pt}<{\centering}|m{46pt}<{\centering}|m{46pt}<{\centering}|}
\hline
$L_{i}$& $E_{M_{0}}$ < - $E_{M}^{T}$ & $|E_{M_{0}}|\leq E_{M}^{T}$ & $|E_{M_{0}}| > E_{M}^{T}$ \\ \hline
$L_{3} \& L_{4} $& $e_{5}$ & $e_{3}$ & $-$ \\ \hline
$L_{6}$& $-$ & $e_{4}$ & $e_{4}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Rules of selecting $e_{q}$.}\label{tab:4}
\centering%
{\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}
{|m{42pt}<{\centering}|m{46pt}<{\centering}|m{46pt}<{\centering}|m{46pt}<{\centering}|}
\hline
$L_{i}$& $E_{M_{0}}$ < - $E_{M}^{T}$ & $|E_{M_{0}}|\leq E_{M}^{T}$ & $|E_{M_{0}}| > E_{M}^{T}$ \\ \hline
$L_{3} \& L_{4} $& $e_{5}$ & $e_{3}$ & $-$ \\ \hline
$L_{1}$& $e_{3}$ & $e_{1}$ & $e_{2}$ \\ \hline
$L_{2}$& $e_{1}$ & $e_{1}$ & $e_{2}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

anyone can help?thanks

Comment: `\secounter{table}{2}`, for example.

Comment: @marmot thanks for your answer, but I need to change the number, not start to numerling here```

Comment: Sorry, I have misunderstood the question. Could you please upgrade your example to a full example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, and describe more precisely what you want?

Comment: @marmot I edited my question, hope you can understand, thanks for your attention:)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possibility to achieve this.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf} 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol, nonfloat}  %% for two columns. NEVER REMOVE!!
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Rules of selecting $e_{q}$.}\label{tab:1}
\centering%
{\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}
{|m{42pt}<{\centering}|m{46pt}<{\centering}|m{46pt}<{\centering}|m{46pt}<{\centering}|}
\hline
$L_{i}$& $E_{M_{0}}$ < - $E_{M}^{T}$ & $|E_{M_{0}}|\leq E_{M}^{T}$ & $|E_{M_{0}}| > E_{M}^{T}$ \\ \hline
$L_{3} \& L_{4} $& $e_{5}$ & $e_{3}$ & $-$ \\ \hline
$L_{1}$& $e_{3}$ & $e_{1}$ & $e_{2}$ \\ \hline
$L_{2}$& $e_{1}$ & $e_{1}$ & $e_{2}$ \\ \hline
$L_{5}$& $-$ & $e_{2}$ & $e_{4}$ \\ \hline
$L_{6}$& $-$ & $e_{4}$ & $e_{4}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{table}
\addtocounter{table}{1}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Rules of selecting $e_{q}$.}\label{tab:3}
\centering%
{\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}
{|m{42pt}<{\centering}|m{46pt}<{\centering}|m{46pt}<{\centering}|m{46pt}<{\centering}|}
\hline
$L_{i}$& $E_{M_{0}}$ < - $E_{M}^{T}$ & $|E_{M_{0}}|\leq E_{M}^{T}$ & $|E_{M_{0}}| > E_{M}^{T}$ \\ \hline
$L_{3} \& L_{4} $& $e_{5}$ & $e_{3}$ & $-$ \\ \hline
$L_{5}$& $-$ & $e_{2}$ & $e_{4}$ \\ \hline
$L_{6}$& $-$ & $e_{4}$ & $e_{4}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{table}

\addtocounter{table}{-2}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Rules of selecting $e_{q}$.}\label{tab:2}
\centering%
{\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}
{|m{42pt}<{\centering}|m{46pt}<{\centering}|m{46pt}<{\centering}|m{46pt}<{\centering}|}
\hline
$L_{i}$& $E_{M_{0}}$ < - $E_{M}^{T}$ & $|E_{M_{0}}|\leq E_{M}^{T}$ & $|E_{M_{0}}| > E_{M}^{T}$ \\ \hline
$L_{3} \& L_{4} $& $e_{5}$ & $e_{3}$ & $-$ \\ \hline
$L_{6}$& $-$ & $e_{4}$ & $e_{4}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{table}

\addtocounter{table}{1}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Rules of selecting $e_{q}$.}\label{tab:4}
\centering%
{\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}
{|m{42pt}<{\centering}|m{46pt}<{\centering}|m{46pt}<{\centering}|m{46pt}<{\centering}|}
\hline
$L_{i}$& $E_{M_{0}}$ < - $E_{M}^{T}$ & $|E_{M_{0}}|\leq E_{M}^{T}$ & $|E_{M_{0}}| > E_{M}^{T}$ \\ \hline
$L_{3} \& L_{4} $& $e_{5}$ & $e_{3}$ & $-$ \\ \hline
$L_{1}$& $e_{3}$ & $e_{1}$ & $e_{2}$ \\ \hline
$L_{2}$& $e_{1}$ & $e_{1}$ & $e_{2}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following convoluted way of setting the `table` counter to whatever you need:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndEnvironment{table}
  {\ifcsname oldtablenum\endcsname
    \setcounter{table}{\oldtablenum}%
   \fi
   \global\let\oldtablenum\undefined}
\newcommand{\setnexttablenumber}[1]{%
  \edef\oldtablenum{\thetable}%
  \setcounter{table}{\numexpr#1-1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{A table caption}
\end{table}

\setnexttablenumber{7}
\begin{table}
  \caption{Another table caption}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Another table caption}
\end{table}

\mbox{}

\end{document}
```

The idea is that `\setnexttablenumber{<num>}` sets the appropriate number for the next table's `\caption`. The numbering is restored at the end of the next `table`.

However, if you have a complete idea of how the numbering should occur, you can use

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\thetable}{%
  \ifcase\value{table}
    0\or % 0
    1\or % 1
    3\or % 2
    2\else % 3
    \arabic{table}% 4...
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{A table caption}
  \caption{Another table caption}
  \caption{Another table caption}
  \caption{A final table caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

An even quicker way would be to adjust `\thetable` directly, as needed, within the `table` environment, without consideration of the actual counter:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{A table caption}
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\thetable}{3}%
  \caption{Another table caption}
  \endgroup
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\thetable}{2}%
  \caption{Another table caption}
  \endgroup
  \caption{A final table caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```